# clustering order by not working

Tags: nosql, cassandra, time-series, modeling, cql

I have just encountered strange behavior when creating time based ordered table.
Normally with the schema of the status_by_user table the latest status should always be on the top, when retrieving the inserted data I am seeing that its not being ordered correctly. (have a look at the cqlsh output)

I am missing something?

```
    -- Running on Cassandra-2.0.4
    -- Inserted some pseudo randomly data from 2013 and 2014 
    CREATE TABLE status_by_user (
       id timeuuid,
       uname text
       status_ts timestamp,
       status_ts_day int, -- YYYYMMDD
       status_comment text,
      PRIMARY KEY ((uname,status_ts_day),id)
    ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id DESC);


    cqlsh> select dateOf(id),status_ts from status_by_user LIMIT 110;

     dateOf(id)                               | status_ts
    ------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------
     2014-03-08 18:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 18:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-08 18:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 18:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-08 18:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 18:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-08 06:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 06:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-08 06:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 06:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-08 06:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 06:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-08 06:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 06:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-08 06:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 06:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-08 06:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 06:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-08 06:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 06:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-08 06:46:37Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 06:46:37Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-08 06:46:37Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 06:46:37Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-08 06:46:37Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-08 06:46:37Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-15 19:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-15 19:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-15 19:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-15 19:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-15 19:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-15 19:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-15 19:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-15 19:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-15 19:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-15 19:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-15 19:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-15 19:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-15 17:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-15 17:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-15 17:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-15 17:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-15 17:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-15 17:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-15 17:46:37Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-15 17:46:37Romance Standard Time
     2014-03-15 17:46:37Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-15 17:46:37Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-19 01:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-19 01:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-19 01:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-19 01:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-19 01:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-19 01:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-19 01:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-19 01:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-19 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-19 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-19 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-19 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-19 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-19 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-19 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-19 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-19 01:46:37Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-19 01:46:37Romance Standard Time
     2013-10-24 00:46:39Romance Daylight Time | 2013-10-24 00:46:39Romance Daylight Time
     2013-10-24 00:46:39Romance Daylight Time | 2013-10-24 00:46:39Romance Daylight Time
     2013-10-24 00:46:38Romance Daylight Time | 2013-10-24 00:46:38Romance Daylight Time
     2013-10-24 00:46:37Romance Daylight Time | 2013-10-24 00:46:37Romance Daylight Time
     2013-10-24 00:46:37Romance Daylight Time | 2013-10-24 00:46:37Romance Daylight Time
     2013-10-24 00:46:37Romance Daylight Time | 2013-10-24 00:46:37Romance Daylight Time
 ? ->2013-12-25 01:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-25 01:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-25 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-25 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-25 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-25 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-25 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-25 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2013-12-25 01:46:37Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-25 01:46:37Romance Standard Time
 ? ->2014-01-16 01:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-16 01:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-01-16 01:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-16 01:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-01-16 01:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-16 01:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-01-16 01:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-16 01:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-01-16 01:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-16 01:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-01-16 01:46:39Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-16 01:46:39Romance Standard Time
     2014-01-16 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-16 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-01-16 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-16 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-01-16 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-16 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-01-16 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-16 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-01-16 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-16 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     2014-01-16 01:46:38Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-16 01:46:38Romance Standard Time
     ..
     ..
    (110 rows)
```

**Update:**

I thought that the partitioning part “(uname,status_ts_day)” of the primary key was not taking into account when ordering the data, knowing that ordering is done by the clustering key “id”.

Can someone clarify this please?

```
    cqlsh> select uname,status_ts_day,dateOf(id), status_ts from trans.status_by_user LIMIT 110;

     uname  | status_ts_day | dateOf(id)                               | status_ts
    --------+---------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------
     test47 |      20140319 | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test47 |      20140319 | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test47 |      20140319 | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test47 |      20140319 | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test47 |      20140319 | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test47 |      20140319 | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test47 |      20140319 | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test47 |      20140319 | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-19 06:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test10 |      20140114 | 2014-01-14 13:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-14 13:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test10 |      20140114 | 2014-01-14 13:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-14 13:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test10 |      20140114 | 2014-01-14 13:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-14 13:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test10 |      20140114 | 2014-01-14 13:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-14 13:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test10 |      20140114 | 2014-01-14 11:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-14 11:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test10 |      20140114 | 2014-01-14 11:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-14 11:13:20Romance Standard Time
      test2 |      20140123 | 2014-01-23 12:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-23 12:13:20Romance Standard Time
      test2 |      20140123 | 2014-01-23 12:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-23 12:13:20Romance Standard Time
      test2 |      20140123 | 2014-01-23 12:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-23 12:13:20Romance Standard Time
      test2 |      20140123 | 2014-01-23 12:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-23 12:13:20Romance Standard Time
      test2 |      20140123 | 2014-01-23 12:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-01-23 12:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test66 |      20131120 | 2013-11-20 12:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2013-11-20 12:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test66 |      20131120 | 2013-11-20 12:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2013-11-20 12:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test66 |      20131120 | 2013-11-20 12:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2013-11-20 12:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test66 |      20131120 | 2013-11-20 12:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2013-11-20 12:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test66 |      20131120 | 2013-11-20 12:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2013-11-20 12:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test34 |      20131223 | 2013-12-23 00:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-23 00:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test34 |      20131223 | 2013-12-23 00:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2013-12-23 00:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test33 |      20140305 | 2014-03-05 06:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-05 06:13:20Romance Standard Time
     test33 |      20140305 | 2014-03-05 06:13:20Romance Standard Time | 2014-03-05 06:13:20Romance Standard Time

    (110 rows)
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Could you include uname in your select query?  I bet that if you do that, you will see that the results are also sorted by user, which is part of the partition key, but is omitted in your select statement.

Removing a column from the query will not reorder the results; rows are still processed in the same order by the engine.

Comment: I thought that the partitioning part “(uname,status_ts_day)” of the primary key was not taking into account when ordering the data, knowing that ordering is done by the clustering key “id”.

Can someone clarify this please?

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#createTablepartitionClustering
"rows for a given partition key are stored in the order induced by the clustering columns"

Comment: That wording might be a little ambiguous.  Clustering only comes into play within a row subset defined by a unique partition key value.   Think of it as a 2 step algorithm when determining where a row goes: (1) Look at the partition key value and use that to determine which storage node the row goes to; (2) Look at clustering key value to determine where to place the row within that node.  As you can tell, partition key is always the first factor that determines final location; any further ordering can only be done within limits established by the partition key.